# How to execute HTML file on iPhone (Objective C)?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, file, url

I am trying to launch an HTML file from within Objective C on the iPhone. I have created the file but I can not get it execute.  I suspect I have not formed the URL quite correctly or specified the openURL command correctly.

Here is the code:

`NSLog(@"HTMLurl: %@", [HTMLurl absoluteURL]);
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:HTMLurl])
    {
        NSLog(@"URL failed to open.");
    }`

Here is what HTMLurl contains:

file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/E43AB0A2-C868-497C-9164-DA101372AD5D/Documents/HTMLfileout.html

I was able to use the identical code to cause audio to play, specified in another url:

file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/E43AB0A2-C868-497C-9164-DA101372AD5D/Documents/audiofileout.mp3

But the html code returns a nil and nothing happens.

Here is how I create the url:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* HTMLFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HTMLfileout.html"];
HTMLurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:HTMLFilePath];

NSLog(@"HTMLurl: %@", [HTMLurl absoluteURL]);
NSData* outputData = [LTTInterface getCompressedHTMLData];
[outputData retain];
```

Thank you in advance.  I know there are a lot of already answered questions about formatting  url's but I can't dope this out on my own.

Yours,
Ken

Comment: Execute an HTML file? You mean you want to display the HTML file like on a browser?

Comment: Yes, display the HTML file on (in) a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the documentation for the `openURL:` in [UIApplication](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

UIKit supports the http:, https:, tel:, and mailto: schemes.

**Update:**

Use [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
[_webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style='background-color:#000; color:#FFF'>Test</body></html>",content] baseURL:nil];
```

Use your string instead of the given html string.

Comment: Yes, I've been spending a lot of time there, doesn't mean I'm bright enough to understand it!  I am a bit befuddled by all the options, I think I am not matching up the format of my URL with the right calling format. But that is just a guess.

Comment: Did my answer matches your requirement or if you still have any doubt, please post it.

Comment: Gomathi, I crashed out last night before you updated your answer.  Now I have to figure out how to implement webview, I found an example here, http://www.chrisdanielson.com/tag/uiwebview/.  I should get to this later today, thank you.

Comment: I think we are getting close, but so far no cigar.  I preloaded the HTML file and hardcoded the address for testing.  Using  your code:/

Comment: I think we are getting close, but so far no cigar.  I preloaded the HTML file and hardcoded the address for testing.  Using code per what you suggested I simply got my address line displayed on the screen.
        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/E43AB0A2-C868-497C-9164-DA101372AD5D/Documents/HTMLfileout.html";
    [webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:urlAddress] baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];  

I will post additional examples next.

Comment: WAIT THIS JUST IN!  The following worked: 
    NSString *urlAddress = @"file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/E43AB0A2-C868-497C-9164-DA101372AD5D/Documents/HTMLfileout.html";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];